# Kong Routes does not match and times out

Tags: kong, kong-ingress

I'm following the https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.11.x/guides/getting-started/ page step by step.

Everything works perfectly till the last step.
I install Kong, then deploy the upstream, then create the ingress required.

I'm getting this message after installing Kong
C:\kong>curl http://172.27.46.64:30598
{
"message":"no Route matched with those values"
}

This ip I got from this command
minikube service -n kong kong-proxy

| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kong | kong-proxy | proxy/80 | http://172.27.46.64:30598 |
|  |  | proxy-ssl/443 | http://172.27.46.64:32212 |

[kong kong-proxy proxy/80
proxy-ssl/443 http://172.27.46.64:30598

But curls are always timing out when I try the upstream url /echo -
C:\kong>curl -i http://kong.example/echo --resolve kong.example:80:172.27.46.64
curl: (7) Failed to connect to kong.example port 80 after 2026 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I'm new to this. Can somebody please help.

I can see this line after I create the ingress
ingress.networking.k8s.io/echo created

This is my echo ingress file -

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: echo
 annotations:
   konghq.com/strip-path: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - host: kong.example
    http:
  paths:
  - path: /echo
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    backend:
      service:
        name: echo
        port:
          number: 1027
```

My upstream deployment, service and this ingress is in default namespace and kong is in kong namespace. Not sure if this causes problems.